# Deploytool for MATLAB R2013b doesn't work, what has changed?

Tags: matlab, licensing, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler, mcc

For years I've been using the integrated `deploytool` to create easily distributable *.exe files for my colleagues. 
I installed R2013b a couple of days ago and I can't use the `deploytool` anymore. The log file when trying to package gives this:

```
ant:
<ant>
  <mkdir dir="C:\Users\xxxx\Matlab\programxy\test\for_redistribution" />
  <mkdir dir="C:\Users\xxxx\Matlab\programxy\test\for_testing" />
</ant>
mcc -C -o test -W WinMain:test -T link:exe -d 'C:\Users\xxxx\Matlab\programxy\test\for_testing' -v 'C:\Users\xxxx\Matlab\programxy\test.m'
Test checkout of feature 'Compiler' failed.

mcc failed.
```

This looks like a license issue but out license does include the compiler.

```
license('test', 'compiler')
```

gives '1'.

Is there anything new with R2013b that I'm just missing? Do I have to install some addon for this to work again?

Comment: Im not so sure if it is a licence issue, Matlab will usually mention the word to be very clear. Assuming you do have a licence, I suppose you should contact Mathworks with your support question.

Comment: We've always had the compiler license, but I'll ask our admin on monday if something changed there but I highly doubt it. I have the number of the support at work but since it's the weekend I can't reach anybody at the moment and I was planning to do this until monday. 
Never change a runnung system eh :P

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment: if the problem is a missing license matlab typically expresses this very clearly.

Judging from your description I would guess that you did not set up / select the compiler after installing the new version of matlab.

Though it is a bit hard to read, I believe [this site](http://ilovematlab.cn/forum.php?mod=viewthread&action=printable&tid=263651) contains some things to try.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem like a licensing issue. But contacting technical support would be the best option.

Also, check if you have licenses for all the products you are trying to deploy with.

It might be worthy to check out if the compiler you are using with is compatible with R2013b.